# LLVM Error When Using a Pass from Another Pass

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, static-analysis

Here is my LLVM Pass:

```
#include <llvm/IR/Function.h>
#include <llvm/Pass.h>
#include <llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h>
#include <llvm/Analysis/MemoryDependenceAnalysis.h>

using namespace llvm;

namespace
{
    struct MemDepend : public FunctionPass
    {
        static char ID;
        MemDepend() : FunctionPass(ID){}

        virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F)
        {
            MemoryDependenceAnalysis *MDA = &getAnalysis<MemoryDependenceAnalysis>();
            return false;
        }

        virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const
        {
              AU.setPreservesAll();
        }
    };
}

char MemDepend::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<MemDepend> X("memdep", "Memory Pass", false, false);
```

When I try to compile it, I receive the following error:

> In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/Pass.h:388:0,
>   from /home/ahmad/Codes/LLVM/MyPass/myPass.cpp:3:
>   /usr/local/include/llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h: In instantiation of ‘AnalysisType& llvm::Pass::getAnalysis() const [with AnalysisType = llvm::MemoryDependenceAnalysis]’:
>   /home/ahmad/Codes/LLVM/MyPass/myPass.cpp:18:79:   required from here
>   /usr/local/include/llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h:223:37: **error: no matching function for call to ‘llvm::Pass::getAnalysisID(void* (*)()) const’
>      return getAnalysisID(&AnalysisType::ID);
>                                        ^**

How can I compile it without error?

Comment: This is obviously no C code. The question should be tagged as C++ instead of C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the canonical way is

```
MemoryDependenceResults &MDA =
    getAnalysis<MemoryDependenceWrapperPass>().getMemDep();
```

And likewise,

```
AU.addRequired<MemoryDependenceWrapperPass>();
```

You can find examples of the above in the LLVM codebase.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But what was the problem with my code? I run into a similar error (**no matching function**) when I set the pass dependency using the following statement: **AU.addRequired<MemoryDependenceAnalysis>();**. While changing **MemoryDependenceAnalysis** to **MemoryDependenceWrapperPass** solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, you should update both - added that to my answer.

Comment: For this analysis, lib/Analysis/MemDepPrinter.cpp, from llvm source is a good template.