# LLVM: ‘AResultsWrapperPass’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: llvm

I am a fresh man on LLVM. Now I am trying figure out how to use the "getAnalysisUsage" method under the LLVM 7.0

In my (Module) pass, I just use:

```
 void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {       
    AU.addRequired<AResultsWrapperPass>();
   //AU.addRequired<AliasAnalysis>();
   //AU.setPreservesAll();
 }
```

When I try to compile it, I receive the following error:

**error: ‘AResultsWrapperPass’ was not declared in this scope**

**error: no matching function for call to ‘llvm::AnalysisUsage::addRequired()’**

I have search some similar question in this web:

[LLVM Error When Using a Pass from Another Pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338149/llvm-error-when-using-a-pass-from-another-pass)

However, it does not work. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a typo. 
It should be `AAResultsWrapperPass` instead of `AResultsWrapperPass`

After adding the requirement, in order to make use of this analysis (e.g. in a runOnFunction method) you should do:

```
AliasAnalysis &aa = getAnalysis<AAResultsWrapperPass>().getAAResults();
```

Comment: It works for me. Thanks! However, when I try to add other passes, such as DataLayout/TargetLibraryInfo/AliasAnalysis (obtained from examples online), I still receive the above errors ('xxxPass' was not declared in this scope, no matching function for call to 'llvm::AnalysisUsage::addRequired'). Could you please tell me how to find the available passes?

Comment: When a pass does not exist or it was removed/renamed/modified you will get this error. Since you are using LLVM 7.0 which is the latest version many things that you find online will not be available anymore. You need to look at the current LLVM codebase to figure what is available and where.

Comment: You are right. The available pass can be found by searching the source code of LLVM.